# help with the fundamental matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let
$$
y'=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}y
$$

Find the fundamental matrix at the point $k = 0$, coincides with the unit matrix.

---

I have found the fundamental matrix with the following column vectors:

$$
x_1(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}
$$

$$
x_2(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)\\
-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)\\ 
\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)
\end{bmatrix}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}
$$

$$
x_3(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)\\
-\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)\\ 
\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t)
\end{bmatrix}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}
$$

but I do not understand the part that says that at point $0$ coincides with the unit matrix. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

So you need to find a fundamental matrix solution $Y(t)$ such that $Y(0)=I$, where $I$ is an identity matrix.

Hint: If you have two fundamental matrices, then 
$$
Y(t)=X(t)C,
$$
where $C$ is a constant matrix.

Comment: mmm, I do not understand the fundamental matrix evaluated've found 0  $$x(0)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1/2 & \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ 
1 & -1/2 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ 
1 & 1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Right. So yours will not work. Use my hint to figure out how to find the correct one.

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1/2 & \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ 
1 & -1/2 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\ 
1 & 1 &0 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
c_1\\ 
c_2\\ 
c_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 &0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$$ correct?

Comment: $C$ is a matrix, not a vector.

Comment: ok C is: $$C=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
-1 & -1 & 2\\ 
-\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3} &0 
\end{bmatrix}$$ now what?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: my new fundamental matrix y(t) is: y(t)=x(t)*c correct?

Comment: It looks correct, however, I did not check your calculations. So the idea is as follows: Your f.m. is $X(t)$, my $C$ is $X(0)^{-1}$, and your answer is $Y(t)=X(t)X(0)^{-1}$.

Comment: oh, sorry C is: $$C=\frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
-1 & -1 & 2\\ 
-\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3} &0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: thank you very much for your help! =)